# Can I get this timestamp through RPC getblock?

Tags: rpc

[image]

Can I get this timestamp through RPC getblock?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a tool like [Substrate Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) for what you are doing here. These properties are not easily accessible via RPC.

Answer (score 4):

If you just use `chain_getBlock`, one of the extrinsics would be `timestamp.set` as applied by the block author.

This contains the `Compact<u64>` value of the current timestamp, i.e. milliseconds since epoch. It will match with the `timestamp.now` in the state.

Since it is an extrinsic, it is available in all nodes, even those where the state has been pruned - assuming obviously that the chain runtime logic adds these `timestamp.set` extrinsics, which most do.

As explained in a comment from mine below, this approach (like another retrieving the storage) assumes that you have access to a SCALE-decoder for your environment which is able to decode Substrate-supplied data based on the on-chain metadata. If you do not have one, your best only-via-RPC option is to use Sidecar which performs the decoding on your behalf.

Comment: Why do I use HTTP to request the RPC method getblock. Don't you see the return message (timestamp. Now)?

Comment: As explained above, it is an extrinsic. So the extrinsic for the `timestamp.set` call will have the information. (On relay-chains this is generally the first , but obviously could change in order). The decoded extrinsic will have the information, i.e. the decoded part of the extrinsics key in the block.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you be more specific? I also know that it needs to be parsed, but what exactly? How to analyze? Through what analysis?

Comment: Decode the extrinsics in the block. Those retrieved as part of the extrinsics array in your screenshot. One of those decoded extrinsics would be timestamp.set - it would most probably be the first extrinsic if from a relay chain, i.e. [0x280402000b919bbc3b8001](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.dwellir.com#/extrinsics/decode/0x280402000b919bbc3b8001). From this decoded extrinsic, get the first argument to this function - it is the `Compact<u64>` that denotes the miliseconds.

Comment: You only told me the way, but didn't say the specific way? What do you use to analyze?

Comment: What method is used to parse this data?

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot of the way you analyze the data

Comment: It is SCALE-encoded, as per the metadata. Substrate uses this encoding extensively. See these SO questions for background on what that is - https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/277/why-do-i-need-to-use-scale-codec/302#302 & https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/201/how-to-decode-extrinsic-at-json-rpc-calls-databyte-code/203#203 If you don't have a SCALE decoder for storage or extrinsics, then I would really suggest you follow the advice elsewhere and use sidecar which does the decoding on your behalf and provides simple endpoints to access it.

Comment: I'm ashamed of which method I want to use to get the data

Comment: def existing = "xxxxxxx"
        ExtrinsicReader<BalanceTransfer> reader = new ExtrinsicReader<>(
                new BalanceTransferReader(SS58Type.Network.CANARY),
                SS58Type.Network.CANARY
        )
        when:
        def rdr = new ScaleCodecReader(Hex.decodeHex(existing))
        def act = reader.read(rdr)

Comment: Extrasic is parsed in this way, but there is no time in it?

Comment: Do you have Skype as a chat tool? This is my account number- charlie@outlook.com ）, can you add my friends to guide me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136244/discussion-between-andy-and-jaco).

Comment: Ask another question, how to get the result of each transaction?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        UInt32Reader reader = new UInt32Reader();

        String str = "0x280402000b919bbc3b8001";
        String replace = str.replace("0x", "");
        ByteData readA = ByteData.from(replace);

        ScaleCodecReader codec = new ScaleCodecReader(readA.getBytes());
        codec.hasNext();
        Long read = codec.read(reader);
        System.out.println(read);


    }

Comment: I tried to analyze it like this, but the result was not correct. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the block time of a specific block like this.
Keep in mind that this only works on an archive node since a pruning node does not have the state of ancient blocks. You can use an indexer for more performance here.

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const blockNum = 10227995;
const hash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(blockNum);
const header = await api.rpc.chain.getHeader(hash);
const timestamp = await api.query.timestamp.now.at(hash);
const date = new Date(timestamp.toNumber());

console.log(`Block time for block ${blockNum}: ${date}`)
```

Comment: Thank you, but if you use HTTP to request the RPC method. （api.query.timestamp.now.at(hash);） How to write this?

Comment: You mean wirh Curl? You probably would need to calculate the storage hash. There is an explanation here: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/

Answer (score 1):

Substrate does not directly provide an RPC for these kinds of queries. The Substrate RPC is kept minimal and generic.

Instead, we provide a tool called [Substrate Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) which you can run alongside your node, and that provides a REST api for many of the common queries you would expect for a Substrate blockchain.

With this, you can access the same storage item that Oliver mentioned above:

```
/pallets/timestamp/storage/now
```

Comment: Why do I use HTTP to request the RPC method getblock. Don't you see the return message (timestamp. Now)?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Why do I use HTTP to request the RPC method getblock. Don't you see the return message (timestamp. Now)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).